# Accessing a public google drive without authentication using Corona sdk

Tags: authentication, coronasdk, public, google-drive-android-api

I have two public folders in my google drive and I want my app to be able read images from one folder and read and write images to another folder. Is there a way to do this using the google api or any GET method and hopefully without needing to authorize or authenticate the user's google account? Thank you!

It's a cross platform application being developed in Lua using the Corona sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot access a particular drive without any authentication/[authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

> Every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an
>   authorization token. The token also identifies your application to
>   Google.

Same question was also raised in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555040/access-google-drive-without-oauth2).

But there is an alternative if you go further in the [answer of the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23567732). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical) maybe useful if you want to try the alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm searching for! I'll update you on any trouble I run into. Thanks again!