# Is there a way to fetch files from Google Drive without the OAuth consent screen and using a service account?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to use the Google Drive API to collect all files from a certain drive. I went with the service account approach but unfortunately, the drive cannot be shared since the service account's email domain doesn't match our shared drive. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to fetch the files without triggering the consent screen and using a service account.

I tried using the service account to fetch the files which worked but unfortunately I cannot share my drive with the service account since the email domains do not match.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Is there a way to fetch files from Google Drive without the OAuth?***

The simple answer is no.

Here is an answer to a similar question for your reference.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23567732/14500538)

For further clarification and guidance, here is a Google document for your question.

[Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: If the crux of your answer is just another StackOverflow answer, then this question is a duplicate.